# How to convert normal string to escaped string?

Tags: php

I get a normal string from user input, and I need escaped version for another application. How can I convert normal string, for example:

```
saixmmxq
        amimimxmo\qmsimcimsomacmo
                mcai\mcismc        mcidmoc
```

to escaped string, for example:

```
saixmmxq\n\tamimimxmo\\qmsimcimsomacmo\n\t\tmcai\\mcismc\tmcidmoc
```

in php?

Comment: What are the rules / syntax? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It seems like part of what `json_encode()` does, so why aren't you just using JSON?

Comment: I was expecting function similar to htmlspecialchars ...

Comment: Escape to what?

Comment: _“I was expecting function similar to htmlspecialchars”_ - why would you expect anything like this to exist, for such an arbitrary requirement? This does not look like a common “format” used everywhere.

Comment: Do you want it to return the string `\t` instead of the tab character? i.e. convert to an escaped, normalized string? In that case, it'll have to depend on what the escape characters for your destination application is - it'll differ depending on language and how they're reading the strings.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like the “escaping” here consist of doubling already existing backslashes, and replacing newlines and tabs with their escaped equivalent. So it can probably easily be implemented using str_replace.

Comment: "it'll have to depend on what the escape characters for your destination application is - it'll differ depending on language and how they're reading the strings." Is it really so hard to change "\n" to "\\n"?

Comment: OK, json_encode works very well.

Comment: Escaping is context-sensitive. `htmlspecialchars()` exists because there is HTML, a well-known and well-defined language. There isn't a builtin escape function for a random format invented by someone in the IT department of some vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` or `json_encode`

```
$string = "saixmmxq
        amimimxmo\qmsimcimsomacmo
                mcai\mcismc        mcidmoc";
$final1 = str_replace(["\n","\r","\t"],["\\n","\\r","\\t"],$string );
var_dump($final1);

//Or

$final2 = json_encode($string, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
var_dump($final2);

#Output "saixmmxq\r\n amimimxmo\\qmsimcimsomacmo\r\n mcai\\mcismc mcidmoc"
```

Comment: Well, this is risky to say the least, since we have no idea of what the rules are.